# Docking a borderless window with cocoa

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, user-interface, nswindow

I want to "dock" a rectangular bar immediately below the menu bar.  It was quite easy to use `-NSMakeRect()` with the appropriate screen width from `[[NSScreen mainScreen] frame]` and then I set my window style via:

```
[window setStyleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask];
```

which works fine.  I try to possition my window as high as possible via:

```
[window setFrameOrigin:NSMakePoint(0.0f, screenrect.size.height];
```

which *almost* works.  What I see is that there is a gap between my window and the system menu bar that is exactly the height of the title bar of my window if it was displayed.  I cannot push my window any higher.

Is it possible to position a borderless window immediately below the menu?

Comment: It should work, try to create a new window and test it with it. What's results? Or create sample project I will check it.

Comment: I did create a window from scratch and it did the exact same thing.   I cannot reposition the top of a borderless window to the bottom of the menu bar.

Comment: Hmm.. Create sample project with this problem and post it here, it's interesting problem.